# CSS Flexbox equal height rows different divs columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Problem:

I'm creating a pricing list with 3 tiers. Nothing crazy here. But I've got a description which can be variable in length. So I can't use any fixed heights or it will break as I reduce the scale of the screen.

Current this is what it looks like: 
[image: Current Pricing Layout]

You can see that the green line is not aligned whether each other.

Is it possible to align them and make them responsive too using `flexbox`?

I have a CodePen here that has all the code to create this:

https://codepen.io/Justintlai/pen/aaEyXR

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. If you want to align them, than the height of the elements containing description need to have set heights.

Comment: there's a `transform: scale(1.02);` at the middle column. Just remove it and they will be aligned

Comment: If you remove the on hover scaling, then yes its possible by putting the content of the three cards in one horizontal container. I think that that it looks fine even without the green lines being aligned.

Comment: I think he means the middle green lines inside the lists

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `display: grid` instead of flexbox can work better for you (one row with the headers, another row with the descriptions, another with features, etc). You'll have to modify the html though.

Comment: @MOHD NADEEM answer works

Answer (score -1):

```
I used jQuery to resolve the same taking your codepen demo.
```

Click here https://codepen.io/MohdNadeem/pen/bxaodW for the same

Comment: Not sure who down voted this (probably just because you mentioned jQuery -__-), this is a good answer +1.

Comment: @MOHDNADEEM I had a look at your codepen but when I resize the window the lines do not align. Do they align for you? I like the concept though.

Comment: If you want to work this on resizing window just add window resize listener to it. I am just updating the same for the resize issue.

Comment: Also if you want to remove the set height after some width like when you are making each element to full width just add the jquery function to only run within window width function. Like this:
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
    if(jQuery(this).width() > 767){
        //function goes here
    }
});